# YouTube not working on Genymotion (Android 4.2.2 and 4.4.4)

Tags: android, youtube, android-4.4-kitkat, android-4.2-jelly-bean, genymotion

I'm developing an app using Genymotion Android emulator and Apache Cordova.

First of all, I've successfully installed Google Apps on both an emulated 4.2.2 and 4.4.4 devices.

Whether if I try to play a video embedded in the Apache Cordova app using a regular  or I open official YouTube app to play some video, I can't play videos.

In the first case I get the *"An error occured"* error message, and when I try to play any video in the official YouTube app, it cries with a *"connection lost"* error.

Is there any way to be able to play YouTube videos using Genymotion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Genymotion with the same question. They said that they're working to fix it, but suggested disabling HD mode in options (it worked for some users, or so they say).

In my case, I couldn't play videos (also on youtube site). When a video started playing, the browser crashed and I received the following error: "Unfortunately, Browser has stopped". Happened on 4.4.* and 5.0.

Comment: Thanks! You're right about this, I've fixed the issue in versions < 4.4

Comment: They claim to support h264 better in Android 5.1 runtimes so it might be worth trying that... Doesn't help me as I'm trying to make video work in an ARM app, and the Genymotion ARM translation layer is unstable on >4.3, but might help you...

Answer (score 1):

Well,I almost try each and every thing, tried to run **blue stack** , **droid4g emulators**, but same issue i.e you tube video was not playing.

Then I try **Genymotion emulator 5.0 Nexus**, It worked there i.e you tube videos are playing now. (tried on **6.0**,**5.1** and **4.2** but there videos were not playing)

Means only 5.0 version of emulator is playing videos of every format i.e 
"Google Nexus 6 - 5.0.0-API21-1440x2560"