# Play Youtube Video inside an Android App without using Android Youtube API

Tags: android, video, youtube, youtube-api

Is there another way to play Youtube videos inside an Android App without using Android Youtube API? We already implemented a solution using the said API, but on some device it requires to downgrade the Youtube app version to play the video. I already searched in Github for possible library that I can use, but most it are dependent to Android Youtube API. Also tried to embed using WebView, but sometimes it crashes.

I'm implementing another solution by parsing a result from http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=p3ND_O6YYg4 and get the value for "**dashmpd**", then load the value of "**dashmpd**" and the result can be used as a source in Android's VideoView, but it has no audio. I noticed that video and audio have different sources.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to go with Youtube `iframe` inside `Webview` instead of `YoutubePlayerFragment`, you will have some work to "re-code" the Youtube  Player control layer for Mobile in WebView (screen size / keycode etc...).

I've made a working example that may help you to get start with :

`AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yourpackage.name">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

        <activity
            android:name="com.yourpackage.name.YoutubeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Beside, you said you had some crash using Youtube iframe on Weview, maybe you didn't set `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` like above

`youtube.html` in `src/main/assets` folder :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>

  <style type="text/css">

    iframe {
      position: absolute;
      border: none;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <script>

    var player;

    // init player
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '1080',
        width: '1920',
        //videoId: 'Orw8CZpzIDU',
        suggestedQuality: 'hd720',
        playerVars: {rel: 0,showinfo:0},
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
      });

    }

    function loadVideo(target){
      target.loadVideoById('Orw8CZpzIDU', 0, 'hd720');
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

        var playbackQuality = event.target.getPlaybackQuality();
        var suggestedQuality = 'hd720';

        console.log("Quality changed to: " + playbackQuality );

        if( playbackQuality !== 'hd720') {
            console.log("Setting quality to " + suggestedQuality );
            event.target.setPlaybackQuality( suggestedQuality );
        }

        console.log(event.data + " et " + YT.PlayerState.PLAYING);
    }

    // when ready, wait for clicks
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
      event.target.setPlaybackQuality('hd720');
      var player = event.target;
      loadVideo(player);
      return false;
    }

  </script>
</head>

<body id="body">

  <div id="video_div">

    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

    <div id="bottom">
      <div id="player"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

And `YoutubeActivity.java` :

```
public class YoutubeActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webview;

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        webview.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        webview.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);

        final WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/youtube.html");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to implement the WebSetting same as yours, but most of the code in Manifest file and html file are already the same. I hope it works.

Comment: Genymotion is causing the issue. Loading an embedded youtube video in Android's WebView results to Genymotion to crash. I tried to use AVD and an actual device to test this approach, and it works fine.

Comment: possibly related : to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218497/youtube-not-working-on-genymotion-android-4-2-2-and-4-4-4

Comment: Great post! It works like a charm except for changing the quality. I am unable to change the quality to anything higher than 'large' - 480 dp. Has anyone experiences a similar thing?

Answer (score 4):

I also had problems with the YouTube Player API so I decided to build my own player library, based on Webview. It is now opensource on GitHub, you can find it [here](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player).

To get started you just need to add the library to your dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:*last-version*'
}
```

Add the View to your layout:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And initialize it:

```java
YouTubePlayerView youtubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
getLifecycle().addObserver(youtubePlayerView);

youtubePlayerView.initialize(new YouTubePlayerInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitSuccess(@NonNull final YouTubePlayer initializedYouTubePlayer) {
        initializedYouTubePlayer.addListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReady() {
                String videoId = "6JYIGclVQdw";
                initializedYouTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0);
            }
        });
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: How do i make it full screen when my activity and the fragment is set to portrait?????? please help