# Using YoutubePlayer in my android application with hardcode video ids

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is it **legal** to play youtube videos in my android app using video ids from hardcode JSON file. I don't want to call youtube data api to get videos.

This is my Video JSON I created my self.

```html
[
  {
    "title": "GET FREE INTERNET WITHOUT SIM CARD & WiFI ROUTER FREE INTERNET TECHNOLOGY 2019",
    "videoId": "vLRnqUPw16I",
    "cat": "tech"
  },
  {
    "title": "Top Upcoming Futuristic Technologies in Smartphones",
    "videoId": "A1QrPw2ROks",
    "cat": "tech"
  },
  {
    "title": "14 Magic Tricks That You Can Do",
    "videoId": "GmONnOGdOk4",
    "cat": "magic"
  },
  {
    "title": "15 Magic Tricks That You Can Do",
    "videoId": "3_FD_COz61k",
    "cat": "magic"
  },

    {
      "title": "NEW TECHNOLOGIES THAT WILL BLOW YOUR MIND",
      "videoId": "h924kiLlvA0",
      "cat": "tech"
    },
    {
      "title": "10 New Incredible Invention You Need To See",
      "videoId": "HrSnBVIjPr4",
      "cat": "tech"
    },
    {
      "title": "10 Most Unusual Vehicles",
      "videoId": "phFij-01hBk",
      "cat": "tech"
    },
    {
      "title": "Top 10 Magic Secrets Of The Year Finally Revealed ",
      "videoId": "_OoeRA3F06Y",
      "cat": "majic"
    }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this thread: [Play Youtube Video inside an Android App without using Android Youtube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601745/play-youtube-video-inside-an-android-app-without-using-android-youtube-api)

> If you really want to go with Youtube `iframe` inside `Webview` instead of `YoutubePlayerFragment`, you will have some work to "re-code" the Youtube Player control layer for Mobile in WebView (screen size / keycode etc...).

You may also check this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@soffritti.pierfrancesco/how-to-play-youtube-videos-in-your-android-app-c40427215230) regarding `android-youtube-player`, an open source alternative to the official YouTube API.

Comment: you did't understand my question 
I want to use Youtube Player API but I don't want to use Youtube Data API V3 to get youtube videos list to play.
I want to get youtube videos id from my own json file.